# java array diplay lowest student

Tags: java

I have this program that asks the user to input students and their score. Then displays the names of students who got the highest and lowest score. My problem is that my program will not print the lowest score.

Any help will be appreciated.
Below is my codes.

```
private Scanner n;
private int limit;
private String[] names;
private int[] scores;

public Exercise9() {

    n = new Scanner(System.in);
    limit = 0;

    index();
}

public void index() {

    int counter = 0;

    System.out.print("Enter how many students : ");
    limit = Integer.parseInt(n.nextLine());

    names = new String[limit];
    scores = new int[limit];

    while(counter < limit && limit != 0) {

        System.out.print("Enter name : ");
        names[counter] = n.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter score : ");
        scores[counter] = Integer.parseInt(n.nextLine());

        counter += 1;

    }

    if(limit == 0) {
        System.out.print("\n\nNo student(s) to display .");
    } else {
        displayStudents();
    }
}

public void displayStudents() {

    System.out.print("\n\nDisplay list of student(s) and scores : \n");

    for(int x = 0 ; x < limit ; x++) {
        System.out.println("\t" + names[x] + "\t" + scores[x]);
    }

    System.out.print("\n\nHighest : " + getHighest() + "\t\tLowest : " + getLowest());
}

public String getHighest() {

    int theScore = 0;
    String theName = "";

    for(int x = 0 ; x < scores.length; x++) {
        if(scores[x] > theScore) {
            theScore = scores[x];
            theName = names[x];
        }
    }
    return theName;
}

public String getLowest() {

    int theScore = 0;
    String theName = "";

    for(int x = 0 ; x < scores.length; x++) {
        if(scores[x] < theScore) {
            theScore = scores[x];
            theName = names[x];
        }
    }
    return theName;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new Exercise9();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing your variable `theScore` to zero to begin with in `getLowest()`.  Assuming you wouldn't have a negative score, this will never get updated.

Try initializing `theScore` to an arbitrarily high number.

Answer (score 0):

Set your `theScore` to one of your `scores`, try this:

```
public String getLowest() {

    int theScore = scores[0];
    String theName = "";

    for(int x = 0 ; x < scores.length; x++) {
        if(scores[x] < theScore) {
            theScore = scores[x];
            theName = names[x];
        }
    }
    return theName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep track of the lowest score and its index. And if you initialize the lowest score to that of the first student, don't check that student again - start the loop at 1

```
 public String getLowest() {

       int theScore = scores[0];
       int lowest = 0;

       for(int x = 1 ; x < scores.length; x++) {
          if(scores[x] < theScore) {
             theScore = scores[x];
             lowest = x;
          }
       }
       return names[lowest];
    }
```

And of course modify the getHighest in the same manner.()